is it possible to bifurcate a SQL Server database on specific drives?
I have various databases in a SQL Server Instance hosted on-premise on a server, on say, the C Drive.
The intent is to migrate a small portion of this to a cloud provider, AWS.
So, let's say I have 2 databases in the Instance. db_junk and db_migrate.
An IT agent -- in order to perform the migration -- wants me to move "db_migrate" from the C Drive on the server to the D drive. Because they want to migrate the entire drive, and NOT migrate db_junk (costs, and it's junk).
Is it possible to do this? ... Is there an easier way to achieve this? I would think maybe there is an easier way to lift an shift a SQL Server specific db --- from on-premise to AWS-hosted SQL Server (same version) -- without doing this.
But regardless, how can this be achieved?
EDIT: The goal ultimately is to migrate db_migrate from the C drive to AWS.
However, I was tasked with implementing a specific piece --- from C drive to D drive on prem, on the same machine in fact, as I believe the next person prefers to migrate "an entire drive" to AWS, as in their wheelhouse. ... This isn't possible with C drive because it contains bloat and other components not intended to migrate.

It's not clear what do you want to migrate (from C drive to D drive or from on-premise to AWS) and what problems you are facing but I'd look at log shipping as migration tool for one database migration.

Agreed with Sergey. Your Post leaves out the most important details at the key parts of your question. For example, is the D drive still on-premise?...in the same server?...or in AWS? Will your SQL Server instance still be running on-prem or is it being migrated to AWS too?

Ah I'll edit. The D drive is also on-prem. Seems the goal is it's easiest for the IT agent to migrant an entire drive. Not sure it that's the best strategy with a database migration though

I believe you are just trying to move the MDF and LDF files. Here are the steps from Microsoft
To move a data or log file as part of a planned relocation, follow these steps:
For each file to be moved, run the following statement.
ALTER DATABASE database_name
    MODIFY FILE (NAME = logical_name, FILENAME = 'new_path\os_file_name');

Run the following statement to bring the database offline.
ALTER DATABASE database_name
    SET OFFLINE;

This action requires exclusive access to the database. If another connection is open to the database, the ALTER DATABASE statement is blocked until all connections are closed. To override this behavior, use the WITH  clause. For example, to automatically roll back and disconnect all other connections to the database, use:
ALTER DATABASE database_name
     SET OFFLINE
     WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

Move the file or files to the new location.
Run the following statement.
ALTER DATABASE database_name
    SET ONLINE;

Verify the file change by running the following query.
SELECT name,
       physical_name AS CurrentLocation,
       state_desc
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE database_id = DB_ID(N'<database_name>');


The only trouble with this approach is down time to copy files. Log shipping with database rename could be instant.
